# rsnapshot for remote backups?

Tags: rsnapshot

I want to use rsnapshot to make backups from my production server to a remote backups server.

Should I install rsnapshot on the remote backup server and not the production one, right ?

rsnapshot is going to pull the files to backup from the production server and store them locally on the backup server ?

I've just realized that I don't have sudo privilegies on the backup server. Does this mean I cannot use rsnapshot for remote backups ?

By the way, isn't a pity I can't use rsnapshot with a backup space service offered by my hosting provider, just because I have not full control on the backup server, but only on the production one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to cron the rsnapshot job on the backup server, as well as set up a remote connection to the production server in order to pull the relevant data.  If you can perform these jobs without sudo (perhaps a portal service like cPanel?), then rsnapshot is still viable.

Without any way to cron the rsnapshot jobs, you'll be out of luck.

Comment: Indeed I don't have access to crontab -e. I don't have control panel: it is basically backup space provided by my hosting service, it is not part of my VPS.

Answer (score 2):

You can run rsnapshot as any user. You will need to copy the `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` file to somewhere that you can edit it eg ~/rsnapshot/ . You will need to change the `lockfile` directive as you most likely wont be able to write to write to it's default as a standard user.

```
lockfile        /home/patrick/rsnapshot/rsnapshot.pid
```

You then invoke rsnapshot thus

```
rsnapshot -c /home/patrick/rsnapshot/rsnapshot.conf hourly
```

Do you have access to cron as a standard user on the server ?

Comment: Yeah.. and I cannot install rsnapshot using apt-get install but I should compile it I guess.. and some other stuff.. I'm not convinced... I'm afraid I'm going to have permissions issues later...

Comment: @Patrick: I tested my answer and it works fine as a non privileged user.

Comment: I've just downoaded rsnapshot (with wget) into my backup server and I cannot even uncompress it because it doesn't have "x" privilegies (only rw for root user).

Comment: Also.. strange, I can delete it, but I'm not root user.. if I use sudo it says I'm not in the sudoers list.

Comment: And I don't have access to crontab -e. So end of the story I guess.